# Update javascript value and view after clicking on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, openlayers

I can't seem to make this work with javascript. I'm trying to update some layers on the map depending on the checkboxes which are checked. 
This is my code and what I have tryes until now.

html:

```
    <div class="option-layer">
        <input type="checkbox" value="layer1" name="Administratoret">
        <input type="checkbox" value="layer11" name="njesite_adm.kml">
        <input type="checkbox" value="raster" name="njesite_adm.kml">
    </div>
```

js :

```
    var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326');
    var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

    var layer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'http://localhost/maptest/test.kml',
        format: new ol.format.KML()
    })
  });

    var layer11 = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
      source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
        url: 'http://localhost/maptest/test.kml',
        format: new ol.format.KML({
          extractStyles: false
      }),
    }),
      opacity: 2,   
  });

    //**the code to get value from checkbox**
    var filter_options=[raster];
    $('input:checkbox').click(function()
    {
        var name=$(this).val().trim();
        if(this.checked)
        {
            filter_options.push(name);
            console.log('Add: ' + name);
        }
        else
        {
            var index=filter_options.indexOf(name);
            if(index > -1)
            {
                filter_options.splice(index, 1);
                console.log('Remove: ' + name + ' at index: ' + index);
            }
        }
        $('#result').html(filter_options.join('; '));
        console.log(filter_options);
    });


    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers : [raster, layer1, layer11] //this works
        layers: filter_options, //this doesnt work, the map wont shoq the layers
        target: document.getElementById('map'),
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [ 29.8187, 32.3275],
          projection: projection,
          zoom: 10,
      })
    });
```

Am I in the right track? Any help wold be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know where your code is executing to?

Answer (score 1):

When you add filter_options array to the map it has got only one layer. You are trying to add/Remove layers from filter_options array after it has been added to the map. Your layers are actually not added to the map.

Load all layers first :

```
  layers : [raster, layer1, layer11] //this works for you already
```

And then on checkbox change event, handle the layers visibility:

```
layer1.setVisible(true) or
layer1.setvisible(false)
```